# SolidWorks API - How can I get the positions and rotations of all parts for all keyframes/key properties in a MotionStudy (Animation)?

Tags: c#, solidworks

as the title says, I try to get the local position and rotation values of all parts in an assembly that get moved in a MotionStudy. I'd like to be able to recreate an animation that already exists in SolidWorks in other environments like e.g. Unity. Therefore I need to read the time and transformation values of each keyframe in the MotionStudy.
 I've dug through the API but I couldn't find anything promising. I can get access to the MotionStudy object itself, but I can't find valuable information in there. I also tried to get motion features and properties, but the returned objects were not useful at all.

Link to the API section for MotionStudy : [SW API MotionStudy](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/swmotionstudyapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swmotionstudy~SolidWorks.Interop.swmotionstudy.IMotionStudy_members.html)

I really hope that someone has already managed to do this.
Thank you.